# ffmpeg h264 stream decoding artefacts

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec, libavformat, gopro

I am trying to decode a live h264 video stream from a GoPro camera (http://www.gopro.com) using the ffmpeg libraries (libavcodec, ...). The problem is that the decoded video stream contains artifacts. For testing purposes I tried to decode the same stream using ffplay and it contains the same artifacts:

```
ffplay -f mpegts -fflags nobuffer -i udp://10.5.5.9:8554
```

or

```
ffplay -f mpegts -i udp://10.5.5.9:8554
```

[image]

ffplay produces these output messages:
[image]

What could be the reasons for these artifacts? Is there a ffplay/ffmpeg parameter which might eliminate the artifacts?

**[EDIT]:** Here is a raw capture of the video: https://gofile.io/d/v2GOAe .
It can be played back with `ffplay -f mpegts -i gp5raw.264`

Regards,

Comment: Perhaps a simple bandwidth problem. You are using UDP. Could register the stream in a file, and provide it, so we can confirm this.

Comment: Here is the raw capture data: https://gofile.io/d/v2GOAe

Answer (score 0):

The broadcast side is sending packets too fast, and the network is dropping them. You need to send the stream in real time by adding the `-re` option before the input.

`ffplay -re -f mpegts -fflags nobuffer -i udp://localhost:8554`

Comment: The ``-re`` flag is only available on ffmpeg?